# Is my assumption right? Most convenient area for most frequently used functionalities

Tags: gui-design

If I were the designer of Evernote, I would have allowed the user to make full use of the large blank area as showed in the picture below. For example, allow the user to customize this area, e.g. putting shortcuts here, as what was designed in the past versions of Evernote. But sometime ago, Evernote changed their design and now they leave this large area of blank space unused. How would you think? Is my assumption wrong? Or do I miss something?

[image: Evernote]

[May 7] Thanks Evan Lange for pointing out the blank area is designed for displaying messages. But can we design it better in this case?

Comment: We can't answer this. Only the UX team at Evernote can.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is what it is being used for:

[image: Looks like this is what it is being used for.]

If this means there is a little badge that appears there (instead of a long notification), then maybe it is indeed blank. But is that so bad?

Is there something you actually want to be there, or are you simply upset that you can't use this space for yourself? Both are valid.

White space is undervalued in UI design, but becoming more widespread. We are retreating from a long era of bloated, icon-heavy full-function UI, and toward displaying only what is necessary. Perhaps this is a pendulum swing (look at 1960's era electronics, which have one or two controls, compared to 1990's era remote controls, with too many buttons for the human brain to comprehend).

It is possible that Evernote has plans for this area that are not implemented. It is also possible that you should work for them and improve upon their product.

Comment: Understand!!  Thanks Evan! I never realized about that, because I never share my notes with others. For me, it's really bad indeed, because I am doing my daily work in Evernote and I am managing more than 500 notes. I have to switch between different notes very often. Put my shortcuts on the left navibar? It's not enough for me and as I am using a large LCD screen, it always means a long distance for me to move the cursor to the most left of the screen, especially when I am using a TouchPad instead of a mouse.